# What is the best way to import and/or sync Gmail-Google contacts with Skype contacts?

Tags: skype, voip, contacts, google-contacts

What is the best way to import and/or sync Gmail-Google contacts with Skype contacts? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype imports Gmail contacts.

http://www.skype.com/intl/en-gb/allfeatures/importcontacts/

Comment: This link is now dead :(

Comment: Skype now only imports Facebook contacts. You can, however, import and export VCF and CSV text files. Both would require some massaging to go between Google and Skype, and Skype can only store a phone number once; so if you have two people who use the same #, you can only put the entry in one time.

Answer (score 1):

Skype in-build contacts import has a few problems.

We use [Synqit](http://synqit.com) to import Gmail contacts into Skype.

Comment: Warning... app costs $9.50

Answer (score 1):

ON A MAC:

Export your gmail contacts (Contacts > More Options)
Then import those contacts into your address book or Entourage

You can now import your contacts through skype. :)